# Is there a feature that brings a question running out of bounty to the top?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

first off, my apologies if this is not the right place to ask this type of question.

I am wondering, if there already is, and if not, what everyone thinks of a feature that allows questions which have bounties running down on them to make it back to the front page.

This is why, for example I have a question that I had a put a bounty on a a couple of days ago and never received an adequate answer. Unfortunately I think it is probably many pages back and not getting any views.

And I had got the message saying my bounty is running out in one day etc.

So I am wondering, if this does not already exist, wouldn't it be a nice feature for it to return to the front maybe at 24 hours left and 12 hours left for example? Just because it is unfortunate to have a question with bounty go unanswered and such.

Thanks for your time and let me know why/why not you think this could work or if it already is some sort of feature.

Comment: In the list of featured questions, the ones with bounties about to run out are on the top.

Comment: This is the right place to ask this type of question.

Comment: From [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) *Questions in that tab are sorted by the amount of time left on their bounties. The closer a bounty is to expiring, the higher it will be on the list.*